# Replace item in knockout array

Tags: knockout.js

After update i need to replace a item in the ko array.
The problem is with the replace function i need to have the old item.

Here is my function:

```
self.saveMarket = function (market) {
    var item = ko.toJS(market);

    $.ajax({
        type: (item.MarketId != "" ? 'PUT' : 'POST'),
        url: url + (item.MarketId != "" ? '?id=' + item.MarketId : ''),
        data: item,
        success: function (data) {
            self.Markets.push(market);
            self.showList();
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        },
    });
}
```

This should handle both insert and update.
The insert works with the push(market), but if i do an update, how can i replace the old item with the new?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to iterate through your observable array (using ko.utils.arrayForEach or $.each), find the item with the matching marketid, remove that element from array, then push the new one.